# What will be the major product of the following dehydrohalogenation?

Tags: hydrocarbons, elimination

**Question:-**
[image: **strong text**]

**My Attempt:-** 
I believe the answer should be C, because even if 2-butyne is formed $\ce{NaNH2}$ should cause it to rearrange into a terminal alkyne. Hence the answer should be 1-butyne. But the book says B as the answer.

Please correct me.

Comment: You are correct, if the last reaction was heated in extended time. However, $\ce{NH2-}$ is not the best catalyst for zipper reaction. Besides, judging from the question, I believe zipper reaction is not intended for the students in this class.

Comment: The rearrangement happens at elevated conditions (eg. heating). You may read the first line here: [Does a non-terminal alkyne react with sodamide?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90945/does-a-non-terminal-alkyne-react-with-sodamide)